# Reading and sending image as base64-encoded string via REST

Tags: php, javascript, rest, air, base64

I'm working on a RESTful API in PHP that allows, among other data, an image to be posted. In the PHP-based client, the base64-encoded string that gets posted is obtained like this:

```
$string = base64_encode( file_get_contents('image.jpg') );
```

It is then decoded on the API-side simply by reversing:

```
file_put_contents('new-image.jpg', base64_decode($string));
```

This works fine with the PHP-based client, but now I'm trying to test it out with Adobe Air.  The result of what's below is a sizable base64-encoded string, but it doesn't decode properly once it hits the API:

```
var fs = new air.FileStream();
var file = air.File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath(files[0].nativePath);
var photoData = '';

fs.open(file, air.FileMode.READ);

for( var i = 0; i < fs.bytesAvailable; i++ ) {
    photoData += fs.readByte();
}

fs.close();

photoData = btoa(photoData); // base64-encoded string
```

At this point, I'm wondering if `btoa()` is a different encoding method than what PHP uses or if I'm simply assembling the bytes improperly into a string.

Any idea as to where I went wrong?  I've been looking at this for far too long :)

Comment: may be convert byte to string before btoa? see http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3569/pack-and-unpack-bytes-to-strings

Comment: Doesn't help...throws "INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: DOM Exception 5" when pack() is applied.

Comment: For what it's worth, the base64-encoded string is supposed to be about 46,000 characters in length.  I'm getting one with around 146,000...